# Sharepoint Slide Library Image Location

Tags: sharepoint, slider, powerpoint, slide

I have a customer that uses the built in Slide Library in SharePoint 2007 to manage the PowerPoint presentations. Once they upload a presentation to the library, I have to use these slides in a separate Image Gallery Slider I've wrote. To get the slides to show up in the Slider, I need the image html location of each slide. EX 'http://testsite/sites/test/PowerPointSlides/test_pptx'

I can get a link to the thumbnail the slide lbrary creates (http://testsite/sites/test/PowerPointSlides/_t/test_pptx.jpg) but it's small and not readable in the Slider.

Does Sharepoint save the full image of each slide somethere I can get the address of or does it only save each .pptx slide and not an image?